# how to I unload a 300 million row table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to unload a 300 million row table in Oracle and load it back. I have tried EXPORT from Oracle SQL developer on a small table and that works.is it ok to use the EXPORT to do above.

export

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is OK. Though, it'll take some time to export that much data. Make sure you have enough space on the target disk. Don't forget to enable logging so that you could check whether everything went OK.

If you have the Enterprise Edition license, enable parallel export which will speed things up.

---

On the other hand, there might be another options, but that depends on what problem you are trying to solve. For example, CTAS (Create Table As), e.g.

```
create table copy as select * From source;
```

would create a copy of that table (without constraints, indexes, etc., but data would be preserved).

If you explained what you are doing, someone might suggest another approach.

Comment: I need to create: an export scriptadd ROWDEPENDECY V

Comment: I need to add the  rowdependencies clause in the table that has 300 million rows.         I need to create 1) Export script 2) drop table 3) Create table with  rowdependencies claus 4) Import the data back into the table.   Any help in this matter would be much appreciated.   Thanks

Comment: You can rename the old table and create a new table, then insert the data directly into the new table from the old table. That way, you've less network involvement, since your data is no longer leaving the database.